# Clayton-Gumbel (BB1) and Joe-Clayton (BB7) time-varying copulas

Tags: matlab, copula

I'm trying to estimate parameters for Mixed Dynamic Copulas (Clayton-Gumbel and Joe-Clayton)
Is there any code in MATLAB?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [Andrew Patton's "Copula toolbox for Matlab"](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~ap172/code.html). It contains his code for the "Time-varying Symmetrised Joe-Clayton copula".